# Atom How can I get files under the project

Tags: atom-editor

I'm using Atom 1.0.5. I'm trying to create atom package.

I would like to get files name under the workspace.

Is it possible?

```
dirs = atom.project.getDirectories()
for dir in dirs
  for entry in dir.getEntriesSync()
    console.log entry.getPath()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the following two APIs:

- [Project.getDirectories](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.0.5/Project#instance-getDirectories): Get an Array of Directorys associated with this project.
- [Directory.getEntries](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.0.5/Directory#instance-getEntries): Reads file entries in this directory from disk asynchronously.

So you would use `Project.getDirectories` first to get a list of directories, and then iterate through them using `Directory.getEntries`. Each entry can either be a file or a directory (again).

Comment: Thanks for your good advice. But I don't get how to use getEntries method. Actually I don't know how to use callback parameters with getEntries method.

Comment: There's also a synchronous method that returns the results instead of using a callback: https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.0.5/Directory#instance-getEntriesSync

Comment: `dirs = atom.project.getDirectories()
    for dir in dirs
      for entry in dir.getEntriesSync()
        console.log entry.getPath()`